# Interesting definite integral involving exp and trig

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, special-functions, exponential-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following integrals:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\kappa \cos(\phi - \mu)} \cos(\phi) d\phi$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\kappa \cos(\phi - \mu)} \sin(\phi) d\phi$$

for which I want to find an easily computable function. This may be either a closed form, or something in terms of special functions that are available in most scientific computing libraries (e.g. [scipy.special](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html)).

I found the following result on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions), which may be useful. 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{x \cos(\theta)} d\theta = 2\pi I_0(x),$$
where $I_0(x)$ is the modified [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind, of order 0.

I want to apologize in advance if this is a basic question; I have not had formal training in advanced calculus (beyond highschool), except for a few online lectures and wikipedia reading.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wenn you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\cos`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: You are trying to solve for what:  $\kappa$ or $\mu$ ??  Or maybe you are trying to **evaluate** the integrals?

Comment: Fixed the terminology: solve -> evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$f(x):=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{x \cos(\phi)}\;d\phi=2\pi I_0(x)$$
since $I'_0(x)=I_1(x)$ and using derivation under the integral sign this becomes :
$$f'(x)=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{x \cos(\phi)}\;\cos(\phi) \;d\phi=2\pi I'_0(x)=2\pi I_1(x)$$

Let's rewrite your first integral (using the substitution $\theta:=\phi - \mu$) :
\begin{align}
I_c:&=\int_{-\mu}^{2\pi-\mu} e^{\kappa \cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta+\mu)\;d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\kappa \cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta+\mu)\;d\theta\\
&=\cos(\mu)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\kappa \cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta)\;d\theta-\sin(\mu)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\kappa \cos(\theta)} \sin(\theta)\;d\theta\\
&=2\pi\cos(\mu)I_1(\kappa)+\sin(\mu)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\kappa \cos(\theta)} \;d\cos(\theta)\\
&=2\pi\cos(\mu)I_1(\kappa)+\sin(\mu)\frac{e^{\kappa\cos(2\pi)}-e^{\kappa\cos(0)}}{\kappa}\\
I_c&=2\pi\cos(\mu)\;I_1(\kappa)
\end{align}

The same way I got the second integral as :

$\qquad\qquad\qquad I_s=2\pi\sin(\mu)\;I_1(\kappa)$

For interesting properties and rewriting of the modified Bessel function $I_1$ see the excellent references available :

- [Abramowitz & Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_374.htm) (with a picture of $I_1$ and numerical approximations page $378$)
- [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25) (kind of online successor of A & S)
- [Wolfram functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/) (very large database of information).

Comment: +1 for the answer.  That said, although I make much use of the DLMF, I find it sorely lacking compared to A & S with respect to computational use (i.e., approximations, integrals, sums, products, etc.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You are right @Ron A&S is missing here (I updated my answer). I don't know why I forgot it here since I am fond of this book !

Comment: You are welcome @JohnvonN. (really? :-)). Should something be unclear let me know...